# Best way to assign values of an array to a struct

Tags: ruby

I have the following struct

```
Traditional = Struct.new(:a, :b, c:)
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

and an array containing the values of all the fields in the struct in the same order as they're defined in the struct. What's the best way of passing the values from the array to their corresponding struct fields?

So that I can do:

```
my_struct[:a] => 1
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to have 31 instance variables to make your point? How about, say, 3? Please also give an example of a 3-element array and show your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has splat operator which will do exactly what you need:

```
obj = Traditional.new(*array)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for... Thanks!

Comment: Being new to Struct I thought I leave an English translation       
`Traditional = Struct.new(:a, :b, :c)
array = [9, 2, 3]
my_struct = Traditional.new(*array)
p my_struct[:a]
p my_struct.inspect`

Comment: Never mind. This mini markdown is useless. I guess my five minutes of fame is up. Oh well, back to work!